# Matlab convert date string to timestamps using datenum problems

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. I am trying to use datenum function to parse date string and convert to timestamps(like in Java, getTime()).Then, I want to find out the difference between two dates in seconds.

```
datenum('2013-02-21T00:39:19Z','yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss')-datenum('2013-02-21T00:34:19Z','yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss')
```

If I run the function above, I get 0.0035 which I have no idea what kind of value it is.

Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Matlab help says:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

> A serial date number represents the **whole and fractional number of
>   days** from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000).

I reckon your answer is maybe 0.0035 days so to get seconds I guess its

```
ans*24*60*60
```

Comment: Thanks god… I've searched for the matlab date2num "enconding" for hours, thinking it was something complex. I don't believe I didn't read that. Thank you very much, sir! (I think I might need to stop working for a while hahahah)

Answer (score 6):

Your result is in datenum format as Dan says. But if you want to find elapsed time in seconds, there is a function that does exactly what you want.

You can use [`etime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/etime.html) to find elapsed time between two date vectors.

```
d1 = datevec('2013-02-21T00:39:19Z','yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss');
d2 = datevec('2013-02-21T00:34:19Z','yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss');

elapsedTime = etime(d1,d2) % Elapsed time in seconds

elapsedTime =

   300
```